# How do I delete a word and previous white space in VIM?

Tags: vim, neovim

`^` denotes char under cursor for vim

**Please dont answer with `T` motion because it will require me to know the last character , which helps me but I want to know if there is any other way**

I have a line of text:

```
these are test words
```

now if I want to delete the word `test`.

If my cursor is at the beginning of the word

```
these are test words
          ^
```

I press `dw` it does exactly what I want, deletes `test` and **spaces** after it till next word ie 'words', I understand this works because `w` motion is **exclusive** and it doesn't include the beginning character of next word

However if I am at end of the word then how can I delete towards left direction and remove those white spaces (between `are` and 'test' as well):

```
these are test words
             ^
```

when I press `dgE` it deletes the `e` at the end of `are` as it tries to reach the end of previous word and deletes it as well, resulting in

```
these ar words
```

I tried to force this command to be exclusive but it excludes on right side and not on left side

I want end result to be:

```
these are words
```

**Please dont answer with `T` or `F` motion**

Comment: I tinkered with the answer a bit and found out that I have a follow-up up  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77132935/how-do-i-delete-a-word-and-previous-white-space-in-vim-when-it-has-unequal-spa

Answer (score 3):

Press `daw` (mnemo: delete a word) as explained in [`:help aw`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#aw). It will delete the entire word and the white space behind it.

Comment: this does exactly what I asked for. thank you

Comment: I had a follow up :P 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77132935/how-do-i-delete-a-word-and-previous-white-space-in-vim-when-it-has-unequal-spa

Comment: I removed the accepted answer check because this seems to be removing spaces from after the word.

Comment: Your question does not ask for what you want to know. Now will there be any way for anybody to post an answer you will accept?