# How do I delete a word and previous white space in VIM { when it has unequal spaces on both sides }?

Tags: vim, neovim

`^` denotes char under cursor for vim

**Please dont answer with `T` motion because it will require me to know the last character , which helps me but I want to know if there is any other way**

I have a line of text:

```
these are test words
```

now if I want to delete the word `test`.

If my cursor is at the beginning of the word

```
these are test words
          ^
```

I press `dw` it does exactly what I want, deletes `test` and **spaces** after it till next word ie 'words', I understand this works because `w` motion is **exclusive** and it doesn't include the beginning character of next word

However if I am at end of the word then how can I delete towards left direction and remove those white spaces (between `are` and 'test' as well):

```
these are test words
             ^
```

when I press `dgE` it deletes the `e` at the end of `are` as it tries to reach the end of previous word and deletes it as well, resulting in

```
these ar words
```

I tried to force this command to be exclusive but it excludes on right side and not on left side

I want end result to be:

```
these are words
```

**Please dont answer with `T` or `F` motion**

---

**Additional note**

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77132033/how-do-i-delete-a-word-and-previous-white-space-in-vim) previously and the answer I got was using `daw` which works if there is only one white space character after and before the word we want to work on

eg if the line was

```
these are test     words
             ^
```

ie there are extra spaces on right side of the word, then if I do `daw` it doesn't do what I want it to do, I want white space on left side to go away but it clears on right side

ie with `daw` output is `there are words`

what I want is `these are     words`

Comment: well you asked for not using `T` or `F` but that is exactly what I would do. `dT x` (note the space) does exactly what you supplied in the last example. You don't need to know the character if you use space.

Comment: ... or `dF x` if you want to remove the leading space.

Answer (score 2):

Oddly enough, Vim does not provide a built-in command for every conceivable editing task. In this case, you may have to issue several commands to achieve your goal.

If there's only one (or few) white space before "test", I'd go for `diwX` which will delete the word but let all white space untouched and then remove spaces with one (or several) presses of `X`. See `:help iw`.

For a more complex white space scenario, I'd use the `:substitute` command like this:

```vim
:s/\s*test
```

This will match any number of white space `\s*` followed by the word "test" and replace the match with nothing, deleting it. You can use <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd> to quickly insert the word under the cursor into the command line as explained in `:help c_CTRL-R_CTRL-W`.

Answer (score 2):

> I tried to force this command to be exclusive but it excludes on right side and not on left side

"Exclusive" motion only excludes on the right side. No matter if it is "a backward" or "a forward" motion.

There's no motion for every kind of user preferences. In this case, you'll need first to position the cursor at the left space and only then delete to the next word's end (inclusive). That is, `gelde` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use`T`or `F`, I'd actually use `diw` and when I realize there's additional whitespace repeat that command with the `.` key.